# Hair Glitch Issue

Tags: the-witcher-3

PC Specs: 4 GB RAM DDR4, i5 6th gen (NOTE: I don't have any graphics card.)

Issue:

Everything runs fine in ultra-low settings and vsync off. I haven't messed with any other settings.

In certain scenes, the hair tends to get messed up. I redownloaded the game and then performed a clean install, and still, the issue persists.

I didn't have any hair issues with any other games I have ever played, and I do play a lot.

Example:  Assassin's Creed Trilogy, Mortal Kombat, Batman Arkham Knight, etc.

[image: Sample One]

[image: Sample Two]

Comment: You should try and post screenshots instead of photos. It's hard to determine which parts are actual graphical problems, and which parts are problems with the photo itself.

Comment: ...and explain what "messed up" means.

Comment: I assume you mean the black feathery bits on their shoulders? It's very likely to be a symptom of your underpowered device.

Comment: Exactly:- I mean those " black feathery bits " those should have been proper hairs.

Comment: '***NOTE: I don't have any graphics card***' I think your question contains the answer

Comment: Ok thanx for all the input it seems I am far overdue for an upgrade and will do it soon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Steam's page for the game, the following are minimum requirements for the game:

- Intel CPU Core i5-2500k @ 3.3GHz or AMD Phenom II X4 940
- 6 GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 or AMD Radeon HD 7870

You don't seem to meet even the basic processor and RAM requirements, not to mention a missing GPU in the mix. You should expect behavior like this, and worse. The developer sets a minimum standard for good reason.